# Need help understanding the proof that the character of the permutation representation of group always contains the trivial character.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let a finite group $G$ act on a finite set $X$ and let $\rho$ be the representation of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}X$ via $\rho(g)\left(\sum_x a_xe_x\right)=\sum_x a_xe_{gx}$.

Then in my notes I have the proof of the fact that the character of this representation, $\pi_X$, must contain the trivial character $1_G$ in it's decomposition into irreducible characters as follows:

"$\langle e_{x_1}+\ldots e_{x_n}\rangle$ is a trivial $G$-subspace with $G$-invariant complement $\{ \sum_x a_xe_x\ |\ \sum_x a_x=0\}$."

I can see why this is $G$ invariant and why it has that $G$ invariant complement but I can't see why that would imply that $\pi_X$ contains $1_G$ (the trivial character) in it's decomposition into irreducible characters.

Comment: The vector $S=e_{x_1}+e_{x_2}+\cdots+e_{x_n}$ satisfies $g\cdot S=S$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: Because the trivial character is the character of the representation on the trivial subspace.

Comment: Alternatively you can observe that the inner product of $\pi_X$ and $1_G$ contains only non-negative terms, and that at least one term is strictly positive.